# Fastest MySQL peformance updating a single field in a single indexed row

Tags: mysql, performance

I'm trying to get the fastest performance from an application that updates indexed rows repeatedly replacing data in a varchar field.  This varchar field will be updated with data that is of equal size upon subsequent updates (so a single row never grows).  To my utter confusion I have found that the performance is directly related to the size of the field itself and is nowhere near the performance of replacing data in a filesystem file directly.  ie 1k field size orders of magnitude faster than 50k field size.  (within the row size limit)  If the row exists in the database and the size is not changing why would an update incur so much overhead?

i am using innodb and have disabled binary logging. i've ruled out communications overhead by using sql generated strings. tried using myisam and it was roughly 2-3x faster but still too slow. i understand the database has overhead but again i am simply replacing data in a single field with data that is of equal size.  what is the db doing other than directly replacing bits?

rough peformance #'s
81 updates/sec (60k string)
1111 updates/sec (1k string)

filesystem performance:
1428 updates/sec (60k string)

the updates i'm doing are insert...on duplicate key update.  straight updates are roughly 50% faster but still ridiculously slow for what it is doing.

Can any experts out there enlighten me?  Any way to improve these numbers?

Comment: Indexes on 50k of varchar? You'll probably find that the index hashing is what's taking up the extra time.

Comment: just to clarify the field i'm updating is NOT part of the index/key.  the key i'm using for the row is just an int

Comment: Ronaldo I am unable to use the char datatype because the length of the field needs to be greater than 255.  however, i did use the ROW_FORMAT=FIXED when declaring the table.

Answer (score 0):

[I addressed a question in the DBA StackExchange concerning using CHAR vs VARCHAR](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/424/performance-implications-of-mysql-varchar-sizes/1915#1915). Please read all the answers, not just mine.

Keep something else in mind as well. [InnoDB features the gen_clust_index, the internal row id clustered index for all InnoDB Tables, one per InnoDB table](https://serverfault.com/questions/238845/what-is-gen-clust-index-used-for-in-mysql/239554#239554). If you change anything in the primary key, this will give the gen_clust_index a real workout getting reoganized.